# Preventing showing multiple intents for button press in android

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android

I have implemented code in which the UI has a button. On button press, I will prompt an email chooser from an intent.

Problem is when I press the button multiple times, the intent popup shows one by one. Can I stop this by using flags? This is a Xamarin Android project.

Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
intent.SetType(FileType);
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, emailMessage.Subject);
if (!emailMessage.IsLinkInclude && !emailMessage.IsAlternateFileInclude){
    intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, AssetPathHelper.GetAssetUri(item, context));
}

intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ResetTaskIfNeeded);
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, Html.FromHtml(emailMessage.Message));
if (intent.ResolveActivity(context.PackageManager) != null){
    context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, AndroidStringLoader.GetStringValue(Resource.String.SendEmailText)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable the button in `onClick()` and once the intended operation is done, enable the button.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    btn.setEnabled(false);
    //some operation may be async
}

public void onOperationFinished() {
    btn.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: but this intent will be in a seperate layer , soo , i was wondering there is a way to do this with intent

Comment: Can you update your question explaining what you mean by _separate layer_

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, here is my solution to avoid it by placing a timer between two consecutive click.

```
private static final long INTERVAL = 1000;
private long lastClickTime = 0;

// onClick of your button code below
@Override
public final void onClick(View v) {
    long currentTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    if (currentTime - lastClickTime > INTERVAL) {
        lastClickTime = currentTime;
        //perform the task here of click
    }
}
```

The other way is setEnabled(false), but for a very fast tapping on button ,  is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no flag for the intent to passed in this scenario , So i have implemented it by following , we can get the fail and success status from it

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivityForResult

```
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Result.Canceled)
            {
                this.shareAssetPopup.isPopupWindowActive = false;
            }
    }
```